# Why don't we write the symmetric term $\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho\xi^\rho$ in a change of coordinates in linearized gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance, linearized-theory

Reading through [this](http://damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/eal40/teach/GR/GR.pdf) lecture, section (5.3.1):

In linearized gravity, when we transform from one set of coordinates to another, the background metric remains Minkowski, but we may think of a metric perturbation as a tensor field on a Minkowski background that transforms as $$h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu}+f_{\mu\nu}\tag{5.65}.$$ This new term $f_{\mu\nu}$ is constructed out of $\xi_\mu$ (a vector that encodes the 4 coordinate transformations) and $\partial_\mu$.

The author writes $f_{\mu\nu}=c_1(\partial_\mu\xi_\nu +\partial_\nu\xi_\mu) + c_2 \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho\xi^\rho + ....\tag{5.66}$

I understand that $f_{\mu\nu}$ should be symmetric under interchange of indices $\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$, but what is the justification for setting $c_2=0$ (which the author does)? Is there some equation that we find after changing coordinates ($x^\lambda \rightarrow x^\lambda + \xi^\lambda$) that have to match $f_{\mu\nu}$ to?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I don't like and understand his approach.

If we consider the infinitesimal coordinate transformation $x^\mu \mapsto \bar{x}^\mu=x^\mu + \xi^\mu$ (infinitesimal means $|\xi^\mu|, |\partial_\nu\xi^\mu|, ... \ll 1 $) and calculate the (full) metric in new coordinate, we get

$$
\begin{align}
 \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} &= g_{\alpha\beta} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} \\
&= (\eta_{\alpha\beta} + h_{\alpha\beta}) (\delta^\alpha_\mu - \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}) (\delta^\alpha_\nu - \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu}) \\
&= \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu} - \eta_{\nu\beta} \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu} - \eta_{\mu\beta} \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} + \mathcal{O}(|\xi^\mu|^2) \\
&= \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu} -\frac{\partial \xi_\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu} -  \frac{\partial \xi_\mu}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} + \mathcal{O}(|\xi^\mu|^2)\,.
\end{align}
$$
On the other hand, we have

$$
 \frac{\partial \xi_\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu} = \frac{\partial \xi_\nu}{\partial x^\mu} + \mathcal{O}(|\xi^\mu|^2)\,.
$$
That is, the new (full) metric reads

$$
 \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} + \mathcal{O}(|\xi^\mu|^2)\,,
$$
where

$$
\bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} + f_{\mu\nu}\,,
$$
with 
$$f_{\mu\nu}= -\partial_\mu \xi_\nu - \partial_\nu \xi_\mu\,.
$$

You can also use the Lie derivative of the Minkowski metric in the old coordinate to get the perturbation metric in the new coordinate, see e.g. Wald.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, but I have written an answer, which presents linear perturbation theory on manifolds in great detail, using invariant language. OP might find this to be a useful elaboration on your answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353726/